# Deployment exception in jboss7

Tags: jboss7.x

```
org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to get manifest for deployment "/F:/Projects/OSW/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/apiAutomation.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:73) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: `enter code here`invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:406) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.readManifest(VFSUtils.java:216) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getManifest(VFSUtils.java:199) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:69) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 6 more

Getting above error when I add classpath entry in MANIFEST.MF file.

Here are the my MANIFEST.MF file.

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0
Dependencies: deployment.jsdnapp.ear
Class-Path: ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/log4j.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/castor-1.1.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp-20030825.184428.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
../WEB-INF/lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool-1.5.6.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-resources-1.0.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/databinders-1.3.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/opensaml-1.1.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/dsmltools-1.0.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/dsml-1.0.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.1.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/ldapbp-1.0.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/quartz-1.6.0.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar
../WEB-INF/lib/ejb-api-3.0.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/spring-oxm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar 
../WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
```

Please help me how to resolve this error.

I am deploying one war and one ear file.
war file is depending on ear file.

war file is calling some ejb classes in ear file.

Please help me how to link communication between war and ear.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure line continuations have a space in front of them:

```
Class-Path: ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/log4j.jar
 ../WEB-INF/lib/castor-1.1.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar
```

instead of:

```
Class-Path: ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/log4j.jar
../WEB-INF/lib/castor-1.1.jar ../WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar
```

(note the space in front of the 2nd line)